# Outlook addin open panel after send

Tags: javascript, outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I've created addin that checks recipients on-send.
I wanna inform the person with the taskpanel.
I'm trying to do "Show task pane" from the js to open that panel.
Is there a way to do that?

UI Dialog is a problem cause there old office's versions in my company

As the Emoji addin
[image]

Comment: We do not support launching a taskpane via outlook web-addins when sending, however, we do support executing a javascript function during Send, which you can read about over here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?view=outlook-js-preview&tabs=classic.

If you want to request for a feature for launching a taskpane, you can do that on our Tech Community page(https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to open a task pane programmatically in web add-ins. The best what you could do is to show a dialog window to a user. Task panes can be opened from a ribbon button or notification items.

You may post your suggestion or feature request to the [Tech Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform).

Comment: Eugene's answer is correct. However, there is currently a feature in preview, called InsightMessage via notificationMessages.addAsync. Which allows you to add a Notification Message that can provide a link to open a Taskpane. It's not exactly what you want, but it is somewhat close? 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.notificationmessageaction?view=outlook-js-preview

Comment: It requires a user's action like the ribbon button anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the Answers!
Even if it is in preview, it won't show in old 2013/ 2019 versions
dialog not works as well.
I recommend them to Upgrade office versions